# Can I get the label name from api reference name of picklist?

Tags: apex

I know that you can get all label names of picklist with the following code.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.PicklistField__c.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> values = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

for( Schema.PicklistEntry v : values) {
      System.debug('Picklist Value Label:' + v.getLabel());
      System.debug('Picklist API Name:' + v.getValue());
}
```

Is there a way to get just the label of the specified API reference name?
In addition to the following

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.Ownership.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> values = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

String result;
for( Schema.PicklistEntry v : values) {
//    System.debug('Picklist Value Label:' + v.getLabel());
    System.debug('Picklist API Name:' + v.getValue());
    if (v.getValue() == 'public') {
        result = v.getLabel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way but you can put all the values in a `Map<value,label>`.  Then just use `Map.get('public')`

```
Map<String,String> MapValueLabel = new Map<String,String>();
String publicLabel;

for( Schema.PicklistEntry v : values) {
    MapValueLabel.put(v.getValue(),v.getLabel());        
}

publicLabel = MapValueLabel.get('public');
```

Comment: No problem.  Mark the answer as 'Accepted' if it works for you.